# DevExtreme - ODataStore Url

Tags: javascript, datasource, devextreme

I have an ODataStore:

```
var storeUsers = new DevExpress.data.ODataStore({
    type: "odata",
    jsonp: false,
    url: SERVICE_URL,
    key: "FEATID",
    keyType: "Int32"
});
```

The db is Oracle and `FEATID` is of `Number(38)` datatype. The `ODataStore` is used in a `dxDataGrid`.
When I update or remove a row of the `dxDataGrid` I always have the error of `Bad request, error in query syntax`.
After a bit of research I found out that the problem is the url, at the moment if the `keyType` is `Int32` the url is

```
http://.../DataService.svc/PX_USERS(7)
```

if I change the keyType to Int64 then the url becomes

```
http://.../DataService.svc/PX_USERS(7L)
```

But for my db, in order to work, the url should be:

```
http://.../DataService.svc/PX_USERS(7M)
```

but I have no idea how to change the url. I tried to statically add an M to the column, but then it becomes a `String` and it is still wrong..

Comment: According [this](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Source_Examples/?version=16_1#Data_Layer_Data_Source_Examples_OData_Edm_Literals) article "OData defines some primitive data types which cannot be represented in JavaScript, for example Int64". So, you can try to use the [EdmLiteral](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/EdmLiteral/?version=16_1) class to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your OData requires a key with "M", the key type is Decimal. See the [Primitive Data Types](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem) OData help topic. So, set the **keyType** option to '**Decimal**' to resolve the issue.

```
var storeUsers = new DevExpress.data.ODataStore({
    type: "odata",
    jsonp: false,
    url: SERVICE_URL,
    key: "FEATID",
    keyType: "Decimal"
});
```